# Elasticsearch: Multiple fields, return true if any exists

Tags: elasticsearch

ES version: `5.2 alpine`

I have a document like this:

```
{
    "field1": null,
    "field2": "xyz"
    "field3": null
}
```

I want to return the document if any of the fields above exists/not null.

```
"filter": {
     "bool": {
          "must": [
           {
               "exists": {
                    "field": ["field1","field2"]
                }
           }]
     }
}
```

but I get following error.
`[exists] unknown token [START_ARRAY] after [field]`

Any idea how to do so with this ES version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass multiple fields in `exists` query. Use exists query for each field and wrap them in `should` clause as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "field1"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "field2"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "field3"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you want to return the doc if field value exist, or also the value. This is for returning documents which satisfies the condition.

This can help,

You can use `should` query with `minimum should match` as 1.

```
"filter": {
   "bool": {
      "should": [
         { "exists": { "field": "field1 } },
         { "exists": { "field": "field2 } },
       ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 1,
   }
}
```

Try it, I hope it will work in your version as well.